# jaxb default element naming in lists

Tags: java, jaxb

Suppose I have the following two classes which I wish to marshall using jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "VirtualizationData")
public class VirtualizationData
{
    @XmlElement(name = "VirtualOrganization")
    public List<VirtualOrganization> Organizations = new ArrayList<VirtualOrganization>();
}
```

and

```
public class VirtualOrganization
{
    public VirtualOrganization(String p_name, String p_id)
    {
        m_name = p_name;
        m_id = p_id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    private String m_name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    private String m_id;
}
```

Here's an example of a marshalled xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VirtualizationData>
    <VirtualOrganization Name="localhost" Id="555"/>
</VirtualizationData>
```

I have two questions -

1. If I remove the name part of the @XmlRootElement attribute - VirtualizationData becomes virtualizationData in the XML. Is there a way to change that? After all, why not use the class name as the default?
2. If I remove the name part of the @XmlElement attribute - VirtualOrganization becomes Organizations. Again, why not use the class name as the element name? What if I'll need to have many other classes that will have lists of VirtualOrganization, should I specify the same name in all of them or is there a way to mark VirtualOrganization?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Following lexicore's answer, I wanted to clarify my questions a bit more. What bothers me is the verbosity of these annotations and the fact that I'll have the same strings and annotations in different places. The question was asked in the hope of finding a convention-over-configuration style solution to the problem. Is there a way to create such conventions in jaxb?

Comment: I think you have to elaborate on your case a bit more, maybe add examples. You know that you can use string constants in annotations, right? And if you have the same annotation structures, would it be possible to refactor the Java classes? It is hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: @lexicore - what do you mean by "And if you have the same annotation structures, would it be possible to refactor the Java classes?"

Comment: For instance, if you have `name` and `value` attributes in many classes it might make sense to extract these properties into a superclass. Or into an aggregated class.

Comment: @lexicore - that is indeed the case and these properties are already in a superclass. However each time I have a list with this superclass, I need to specify ALL possible inhereting classes in an XmlElements attribute and modify all lists whenever a new one is added...

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit too hard to reason theoretically. If you could maybe post specific examples? It would be easier to give specific answers then.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there is no (easy) way to change that without annotations because annotations ARE the (easy) way to change that.

Long answer:

1. There definitely are may ways to create element names from Java names (for instance, from the class name here). `virtualizationData`, `VirtualizationData`, `virtualization-data` would all make sense. But one method had to be chosen by default. If it were, like you're suggesting, `VirtualizationData`, you could always ask - why not `virtualizationData`?
2. The same thing here, but with an additional complexity that `VirtualOrganization` is the generic type parameter of the list. When compiling schemas you can easily get something like `List<Serializable>`, but `Serializables` would not really make sense as an element name. So we can conclude that name of the collection item class does not necessarily gives a meaningful name for the attribute. I think you can't define the default collection element name on the `VirtualOrganization` (if this is what you're asking).

I said above, there is no (easy) way to change that. But it is doable. You can write and configure your own annotation reader which would implement different default naming. However I would definitely not recommend doing that. Just use annotations to customize.